# cell of a datagridview to support multiple lines using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have a datagrid view with two columns. the first column is readonly and the other is editable. now i want every cell of the second column to support for mulitilines in each cell. i want to press enter key and come to the next line in the same cell.
im using c#.

Comment: Not really sure that I understand your question. As with all questions; the better your question is, the better the answers will be :)

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing newlines with HTML break-tags:

```
var helloWorld = @"Hello
World";

// helloWorldHTML will contain "Hello<br />World";
var helloWorldHTML = helloWorld.Replace(System.Environment.NewLine, "<br />");
```